# Handle multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This task is tough one for me. Please don't get mad. I'm making dynamic inputs to able for user add more informartion.Expected output if both field was filled, push it to the array. I have one datalist and one input. For both of them I want to use one onChange function to make validation and push to the array. Right now,  in onChange function I'm checking datalist, does value was typed or selected from options.  The problem is that when I'm storing in state, it only saves one sigle value or doesn't push to array. I commented where is the problem in the code. I have tried to reproduced my code : https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/qwg3j2fa/9/

```
{this.state.arrayOfInput.map((item, idx) => {
  return (
    <>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="address"
      list="data-list"
      onChange={e => this.onChooseAddress(e)}
    />
      <datalist id="data-list">
        {this.state.adresses.map((item, idx) => {
          const { id, address } = item
          return <option key={idx} data-value={id} value={address} />
        })}
      </datalist>
    <input
      name="contact"
      className="event_time-inputs event_table_textarea"
      placeholder="Contact"
      onChange={e => this.onChooseAddress(e)}
    />
    </>
)
})}
```

onChange function:

```
  onChooseAddress(e) {
    const { adresses } = this.state
    let address_id = ""
    let new_address = ""
    let whoIsMetting = ""
    // checking if value from "contact" input
    if (e.target.name === "contact") {
      whoIsMetting = e.target.value
    }
    // checking if value is selected from options in datalist
    for (let i = 0; i < adresses.length; i++) {
      if (
        e.target.value === adresses[i].address &&
        e.target.name === "address"
      ) {
        address_id = adresses[i].id
      }
    }
    //if user typed value
    if (!address_id && e.target.name === "address") {
      new_address = e.target.value
    }

    // PROBLEM IS HERE!!!! if both fields was filled pushing to array
    if ((address_id || new_address) && whoIsMetting) {

      let interviewDetails = {
        address_id: address_id,
        new_address: new_address,
        whoIsMetting: whoIsMetting,
      }

      this.setState(prevState => ({
        arrayOfAddresses: [...prevState.arrayOfAddresses, interviewDetails],
      }))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you explain what `state.arrayOfAddresses` looks atm and what you expect from it to look like? Should it just contain objects like `interviewDetails`?

Comment: @BreakBB yes, arrayOfAddresses should contain objects . When both fields filled it should push to the array. Same thing when new inputs adds ,push to the array. state.arrayOfAddresses you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/armakarma/qwg3j2fa/9/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that only one of the three variables `address_id`, `new_address` and `whoIsMetting` can have a value at a call of `onChooseAddress`.

You can never have a value in `whoisMetting` and one of the others together, because `whoIsMetting` only gets a value if `onChooseAddress` is called from the `contact` input and the others if it is called from the `address` input.

I suggest you either stash partly correct values in a different variable (outside of the method ofc) and check for completion before pushing them to the `arrayOfAddresses` OR simply push partly correct entries directly to `arrayOfAddresses` and check for completion before using an entry of this array.